# Leaflet tile provider with fallback and grey scale

Tags: leaflet

I'm currently using two plugins for leaflet:
https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.TileLayer.Fallback to allow my map to fall back to higher zoom levels if a tile for the current zoom level is not available.
https://github.com/Zverik/leaflet-grayscale to make my background map tiles grey scale.
I would like to be able to do both at the same time.

I tried making the grey scale plugin extend the fallback object, but that didn't work.

How can I make leaflet-greyscale rather extend TileLayer.Fallback rather than just TileLayer?

Ideally I want a new FallbackGreyscale object or maybe something like L.tileLayer.fallback.greyscale. But any way in which I can have both fallback and grey scale at the same time would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaflet-grayscale uses an inefficient method to convert the image to grayscale: drawing into a canvas. This is done for compatibility with older browsers. Using this technique makes it work in IE, but complicates compatibility.

If you are only targetting browsers which [implement the filter CSS rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility), the easiest way to accomplish what you want is to modify the [`_tileOnError()` method of Leaflet.TileLayer.Fallback](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.TileLayer.Fallback/blob/e36cde946bd68bb4fac1b087e24927e70336aed8/src/fallback.js#L29) so it applies a [grayscale filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/grayscale) style to the tile, i.e..:

```
style.filter = 'grayscale(1)';
```

Comment: What a simple solution! We could even spare the method modification by just applying a [`className`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#gridlayer-classname) on the Tile Layer and define the filter in CSS! [Demo](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/lirjToLQbGqTiHnc)

Comment: I thought @JPM wanted greyscale only on the failed tiles? Anyway it would be worth adding that as a second answer.

Comment: Hum you are right I did not understand it that way, but this sounds a plausible use case.

Comment: Excellent, the demo works exactly as I wanted it to. Thanks a lot all!

I needed this for an app written in Electron, so no need for IE support.